# Winmm.dll Records Only Mono in Windows 8.1

Tags: vb.net, winapi, audio, recorder, winmm

I have an application that records PC audio that I have been using for years. On my Windows 8.1 computer, my application records only in mono, 8 bit, 11025 KHz. On my Windows 7 computer and all previous operating systems, it would record stereo, 16 bit, 44100 KHz, as it should. Here is a snippet of my code, which of course is found in many references:

```
Public Class frmRecorder
    Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub cmdStart_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal  eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click
        Dim i As Object

        i = mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias capture", 0, 0, 0)
        i = mciSendString("set capture bitspersample 16", 0, 0, 0)
        i = mciSendString("set capture samplespersec 44100", 0, 0, 0)
        i = mciSendString("set capture channels 2", 0, 0, 0)
        i = mciSendString("record capture overwrite", 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdStop_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStop.Click
        Dim i As Object, WaveFile As String = "Test.wav"        
        i = mciSendString("stop capture", 0, 0, 0)
        i = mciSendString("save capture " + """" + WaveFile + """", 0, 0, 0)
        i = mciSendString("close capture", 0, 0, 0)
        FileClose()
End Class
```

Is there some way to record correctly in Windows 8.1? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I never got an answer to this question, however, I switched to using Naudio for my recording applications and this works perfectly.